# Find uninstalled aptitude package which provides command

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

What's the best way to find the uninstalled aptitude package associated with a command? I'm aware of `apt-file` but it's output is usually hard to parse.

For example, `apt-file search ifconfig` outputs 45 results. I could probably use some regex to reduce that even more, but that's far from ideal.

I'd like to be able to do something like `findpkg ifconfig` and see `net-tools` without clutter.

Comment: Since *commands* typically live in a `bin` (or `sbin`) directory, I often find it useful to simply prepend `bin/` to the search term e.g. `apt-file search 'bin/ifconfig'`

Comment: @dessert provide it is kept up-to-date, `apt-file` **will** search uninstalled packages (at least for the repositories that the user has in their `sources.list`/`sources.list.d`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For installed packages

That's a job for `dpkg-query`.

```
dpkg-query -S /path/to/file
```

gives you the name of the package which installed the matched file. You'll want to use the exact path to get an output without clutter, luckily `/sbin/ifconfig` like in your case can be easily retrieved with `which`:

```
$ dpkg-query -S $(which ifconfig)
net-tools: /sbin/ifconfig
```

---

Reversely, `dpkg-query -L PACKAGENAME` prints a list of files installed by the given package, e.g.:

```
$ dpkg-query -L net-tools | grep ^/sbin/
/sbin/nameif
/sbin/ipmaddr
/sbin/plipconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
/sbin/route
/sbin/mii-tool
/sbin/iptunnel
/sbin/rarp
/sbin/slattach
```

See [`man dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) for more.

## For not yet installed packages

`apt-file` provides some options we can use to get rid of the clutter output:

> ```
> -l, --package-only
>     Only display package name; do not display file names.
>
> -x, --regexp
>     Treat pattern as a (perl) regular expression. See perlreref(1) for details.
>     Without this option, pattern is treated as a literal string to search for.
> ```

Therefore, to search for a command's package the following line can be used:

```
apt-file -lx search "/COMMAND$"
```

To make it easier let's define a function:

```
$ findpkg() { apt-file -lx search "/$1$";}
$ findpkg ifconfig
net-tools
```

See [`man apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) for more about this command and [perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) for an introduction on perl regular expressions.

Comment: I'm searching for a command I don't have installed so I can install it.

Comment: I've updated my title :). That gets me close, I'm looking for something like that on the command line.